# Identify which topic has records in Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've been following Kafka consumer class. I'm able to pass topics as a list object. I'm referring to the following article    https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/java.html, but I need to know once the consumer class is subscribed to topics, how can I know which topic is having the records in it. Is there any way to find out? Here is the code:

```
public abstract class ConsumeLoop implements Runnable {
  private final KafkaConsumer<K, V> consumer;
  private final List<String> topics;
  private final CountDownLatch shutdownLatch;

  public BasicConsumeLoop(KafkaConsumer<K, V> consumer, List<String> topics) {
    this.consumer = consumer;
    this.topics = topics;
    this.shutdownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  }

  public abstract void process(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record);

  public void run() {
  try {
      consumer.subscribe(topics);  --> Consuming list of topics

      while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<K, V> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);  --> Which topic is returning the records?
        records.forEach(record -> process(record));    
     }  
   } catch (WakeupException e) {
     // ignore, we're closing
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Unexpected error", e);
    } finally {
       consumer.close();
      shutdownLatch.countDown();
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[partitions()](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecords.html#partitions--) method from `ConsumerRecords` will return a Set of `TopicPartition`s:

> **partitions**  -  Get the partitions which have records contained in this record set.

You can then iterate over that set to get `topic()` names and `partition()` numbers, depending on what you need. For example:

```
   for (TopicPartition tp : records.partitions()) {
     System.out.println("Got " + records.records(tp).size() + " records "
       + "from topic:partition " + tp.topic() + ":" + tp.partition());
   }
```

Comment: Okay gotcha! Thank you

Comment: tp.partition() return the integer value right, so how can I know how many records are there in a topic, because "records" object is from the total topics messages as a consolidated number

Comment: `records(TopicPartition tp)` returns _just the records for the given partition_. `records(String topic)` returns _just the records for the given topic_. See javadoc at https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecords.html